# Good men in robes

Tags: meaning, phrases

> It is time for *good men in robes* to rethink their responsibilities while heeding Edmund Burke's warning: "The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil is for good men to do nothing."
>
> — Babar Sattar at [dawn.com](http://www.dawn.com/news/1144955/wholl-save-the-justice-system)

What is meant by *good men in robes*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the article the quote is from is "Who'll save the justice system? and in it the probity of judges is questioned, including that of high court or superior court judges.

The "good men in robes" therefore can be taken to men that "honest and upright judges" as judges usually wear robes.

Comment: Yes you are right.Thank you very much dear for your kind reply.

Comment: @SaleemUlHaq. Note that in English we use 'dear' as a form of address only to young children and close friends or family members. Adult males rarely use it to other males except, sometimes, to their young sons.

Comment: @tunny I could be wrong in this particular instance, but I rather doubt that *JoAnne* is a man’s name.

Comment: @tchrist. JoAnne's gender is irrelevant. She (or, far less probably, he) is almost certainly not a child, close friend or family member